# Why am I getting a 404 error when I post from an Angular2 app to PHP?

Tags: php, http, angular, post

With the exception of the PHP (which may work, but is so far untested), all of the code below seems to be working. My problem is that I am getting a 404 error when trying to access the PHP file on my localhost server.

I am using Lite-Server, but I have also tried using XAMPP to see if the issue was with the server itself, but in any case I get a 404.

I have also tried using both absolute and relative urls with my post request to no avail. The data is displaying as expected when I check the post header in the Chrome dev tools network tab as well, so the data is attempting to post.

Why can't the browser locate the PHP file?

**My Code**

*Form Component:*

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private databaseService : DatabaseService) {    

    this.quoteForm = fb.group({
        'firstName': [null, Validators.required,],
        'lastName': [null, Validators.required],
        'email': [null, Validators.required],
        'phone': [null, Validators.required],
        'company': [],
        'country': ['United States'],
        'address1': [],
        'address2': [],
        'city': [],
        'state': [""],
        'zip': [],
        'prefContact': [""],
        'referral': [""],
        'queryType': [""],
        'companyType': [""],
        'message': [null, Validators.required]
    });
}

onSubmit(value: Object) {

    if(this.quoteForm.invalid) {
        this.formValid = false;
    }
    else {
        this.formValid = true;          
        this.submitted = true;
        this.databaseService.postForm(value)
                            .subscribe(
                                data => value,
                                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
                            );
    }
}
```

*Posting Service*

```
private _url: string = "/db/quote-form.php";

constructor(private _http: Http) {}

postForm(data: any) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let body = JSON.stringify(data);

    return this._http.post(this._url, body, options)
                          .map(this.extractData)
                          .catch(this.handleError)
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || {};
}

private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if(error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }

    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

*PHP:*

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');

$formData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

foreach ($formData as $key=>$value) {
    $_POST[$key]=$value;
}

$formObject = $_POST['firstName'];
$formObject = $_POST['lastName'];
$formObject = $_POST['email'];
$formObject = $_POST['phone'];
$formObject = $_POST['company'];
$formObject = $_POST['country'];
$formObject = $_POST['address1'];
$formObject = $_POST['address2'];
$formObject = $_POST['city'];
$formObject = $_POST['state'];
$formObject = $_POST['zip'];
$formObject = $_POST['prefContact'];
$formObject = $_POST['referral'];
$formObject = $_POST['queryType'];
$formObject = $_POST['companyType'];
$formObject = $_POST['message'];
$formObject = $_POST['images'];

echo $formObject['firstName'];
```

By the way, a GET requests work, but POSTs do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I did not properly test the XAMPP server because it is indeed working. Lite-Server is not inherently set up to run PHP so my PHP files were treated as ordinary text. I knew it would be something obvious in retrospect.

So to sum it up for the poor folks stuck on a similar problem:

If you are using a local server (like Lite-Server) and you are building an angular app that needs to post to a PHP file on the backend, but your post is returning a 404 error, the problem is likely the server itself. Either switch to something like XAMPP or find a way to make Lite-Server execute PHP as code.

If you use a service within your development environment that automatically converts TypeScript to JS (such as TSC), you can still run it to watch and convert your files while you have XAMPP (or something equivalent) running your local server. I had to edit my package.json as I was running TSC with Lite-Server concurrently.

This issue was the most painful and difficult one I have run into using Angular2 so far, and I feel it is in severe need of documentation.